# In MySQL, return records with specific counts by year

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an orders data set. I'd like to get email addresses where the count of orders are specific counts for each year. Let's say 2000 = 1, 2001 = 5 or less, 2002 = 3.

```
select email
from orders
where year in (2000,2001,2002)
```

That's where I'm stuck. My thought process is pushing me towards using a having clause or a case statement, but I'm at a wall with the condition of considering the counts by year.

In pseudo SQL it'd be:

```
select email
from orders
where count(year = 2000) = 1
and count(year = 2001) <= 5
and count(year = 2002) = 3
```

Comment: We need more information. Please see: [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: https://linuxhint.com/mysql-select-count-group-by/

Comment: were those independent examples?  or are you looking for an email with 1 order in 2000 and 5 in 2001 and 3 in 2002?

Comment: @ysth in the example, I'm looking for email addresses that had 1 order in 2000 and 5 or less in 2001 and 3 in 2002.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do this in the where clause, you have to group by email and apply your condition in a having clause (or have your group by query as a subquery and use a where condition in an outer query).

```
select email
from orders
where year in (2000,2001,2003)
group by email
having sum(year = 2000) = 1
and sum(year = 2001) <= 5
and sum(year = 2002) = 3
```

Comment: That makes sense. I guess I wasn't too far off with my pseudo example. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as bellow.
Note that you can change the filtred values wthin the where condition for the count value and the associated year.

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE Orders (
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  email VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
  year int NOT NULL
);
-- insert some values
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (1, 'test1@mail.com', 2000);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (2, 'test2@mail.com', 2001);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (3, 'test2@mail.com', 2001);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (4, 'test3@mail.com', 2002);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (5, 'test2@mail.com', 2001);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (6, 'test3@mail.com', 2002);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (7, 'test2@mail.com', 2001);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (9, 'test2@mail.com', 2001);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (10, 'test3@mail.com', 2002);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (11, 'test4@mail.com', 2002);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (12, 'test4@mail.com', 2001);
INSERT INTO Orders VALUES (13, 'test4@mail.com', 2002);

--sql statement
select result.email from (
select email, year, count(*) As count from Orders where year in (2000,2001,2002)
group by year, email
)result
where 
(result.count = 1 and year = 2000)
;
```

Output:


email

test1@mail.com